# How i append div in jquery and delete div except first div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append div on click add more and remove that div according to my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add-skill-row span").click(function() {
        $(".add-skils-form:first").clone().appendTo("#appendbox");
    });
    $('#appendbox').on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
        $(this).closest('.add-skils-form').remove();
    });
});
```

this is my code it works perfect but i want to not delete first div and remove delete button my html code is

```
<div id="appendbox">
    <div class="add-skils-form">
        <div class="skill-a">
            <input type="text" class="inputtextbox" value="" name="" placeholder="Enter Your Key Skills" />
        </div>
        <div class="skill-b">
            <select id="key-skills-select" class="defualt-select default-size">
                <option value="3">Advanced</option>
                <option value="2">Intermediate</option>
                <option value="1" selected>Beginner</option>

            </select>
            <a href="#" class="delete-row"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how could i do please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    deleteRow();
    $(".add-skill-row span").click(function() {
        $(".add-skils-form:first").clone().appendTo("#appendbox");
        $('.delete-row').show();
    });
    $('#appendbox').on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
        $(this).closest('.add-skils-form').remove();
        deleteRow();
    });

    function deleteRow(){
        if($('.add-skils-form').length == 1){
        $('.delete-row').first().hide();
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: hello when i add a new div it takes the value of first div

Comment: $('.inputtextbox').last().val('');

Comment: where i use this line please suggest

Comment: Inside here $('#appendbox').on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
        $(this).closest('.add-skils-form').remove();
        deleteRow(); 
        // here
    });

Comment: One problem how to take name in input type when add a new input type for database save purpose

Answer (score 0):

## Another Solution

Check here https://fiddle.jshell.net/o2f0kskf/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add-skill-row span").click(function() {
        $(".add-skils-form:first").clone().find("input[type='text']").val("").end().appendTo("#appendbox");
    });
    $('#appendbox').on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
         $(this).closest(".add-skils-form").not(":first-child").remove();

    });
});
```